# Chrome extensions accessing GUM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm working on a little sideproject in form of a chrome extension which displays the local stream via the getUserMedia API.

First I had issues requesting the gum (getUserMedia) since I tried to access it via the popup.js and the background.js. After some testing I got it working within the content.js, but now the issue was acutally displaying the stream in the popup.html. Further investigation suggested using the inbuild sendMessage from chrome (since the content script has no access to the popup).

So my workflow is now a onClick listener on my popup, on user click sending a notification to my content script, requesting the gum there and executing a callback function from the received message which sets the stream on my video element. The issue now my send stream is altered by transferring it via the sendMessage function, which results in an error setting the stream on my video element, since the stream is no longer a MediaStream object.

My approach is a trial and error approach since I'm neither a webdeveloper nor do I have any experience with chrome-extensions. Any suggestions or help on how I can achive this are highly appreciated

-- popup.js

```
let startStream = document.getElementById('gum');

function setStream(stream) {
  if(stream != null){
    video = document.getElementById('localStream');

    if("srcObject" in video) {
      console.log("videoelement supports scrObject.")
    }

    console.log('stream: ', stream)
    video.srcObject = stream;
  } else {
    console.log("popup: passed stream is not definded")
  }
}

startStream.onclick = function(element) {
  console.log("popup start stream clicked");
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, tabs => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        {from: 'popup', action: 'startStream'},
        setStream);
  });
};
```

-- popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls id=localStream></video>
    <button id="gum">Start</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

-- content.js

```
console.log('content script init')

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
  console.log(sender.tab ?
              "message from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
              "message from the extension");

  if (msg.from == "popup" && msg.action == "startStream"){
    console.log('content script start stream action')
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})
    .then((stream) => {
      console.log('content gum successfull: ', toString(stream));
      console.log('stream: ', stream);
      response(stream);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('content gum error: ' + error);
      response(null);
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

-- manifest.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Some test",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "storage", "activeTab", "tabs"],

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "all_frames": false
    }],

    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon-off-16.png",
        "32": "images/icon-off-32.png",
        "48": "images/icon-off-48.png",
        "64": "images/icon-off-64.png",
        "128": "images/icon-off-128.png"
      },
      "default_title": "World Domination"
    },

    "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon-off-16.png",
      "32": "images/icon-off-32.png",
      "48": "images/icon-off-48.png",
      "64": "images/icon-off-64.png",
      "128": "images/icon-off-128.png"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Extension messaging can only send simple inert JSON-compatible data so it can't send streams. The only solution I can think of is to extract the data from the stream as a `Blob` in the content script, call URL.createObjectURL and send the resultant URL to the popup where you'll fetch this URL or use it in `src` attribute of a DOM video element. Or maybe just send the blob as a `data:` URI (should be less than 64MB).

Comment: thanks for the clarification and hints, gonna try using blobs for transmitting the stream.

Comment: @MrNice - did you find a solution to your issue?